# State garbage collection in Beam with GlobalWindow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-flink, apache-beam

Apache Beam has recently introduced [state cells](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html), through `StateSpec` and the `@StateId` annotation, with partial support in Apache Flink and Google Cloud Dataflow.

I cannot find any documentation on what happens when this is used with a `GlobalWindow`. In particular, is there a way to have a "state garbage collection" mechanism to get rid of states for keys that have not been seen for a while according to some configuration, while still maintaining a single all-time state for keys are that seen frequently enough?

Or, is the amount of state used in this case going to diverge, with no way to ever reclaim state corresponding to keys that have not been seen in a while?

I am also interested in whether a potential solution would be supported in either Apache Flink or Google Cloud Dataflow.

Flink and direct runners seem to have some code for "state GC" but I am not really sure what it does and whether it is relevant when using a global window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

State can be automatically garbage collected by a Beam runner at some point after a window expires - when the input watermark exceeds the end of the window by the allowed lateness, so all further input is droppable. The exact details depend on the runner.

As you correctly determined, the Global window may never expire. Then this automatic collection of state will not be invoked. For bounded data, including drain scenarios, it actually will expire, but for a perpetual unbounded data source it will not.

If you are doing stateful processing on such data in the Global window you can use user-defined timers (used through `@TimerId`, `@OnTimer`, and `TimerSpec` - I haven't blogged about these yet) to clear state after some timeout of your choosing. If the state represents an aggregation of some sort, then you'll want a timer anyhow to make sure your data is not stranded in state.

Here is a quick example of their use:

```java
new DoFn<Foo, Baz>() {

  private static final String MY_TIMER = "my-timer";
  private static final String MY_STATE = "my-state";

  @StateId(MY_STATE)
  private final StateSpec<ValueState<Bizzle>> =
      StateSpec.value(Bizzle.coder());

  @TimerId(MY_TIMER)
  private final TimerSpec myTimer =
      TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME);

  @ProcessElement
  public void process(
      ProcessContext c,
      @StateId(MY_STATE) ValueState<Bizzle> bizzleState,
      @TimerId(MY_TIMER) Timer myTimer) {
    bizzleState.write(...);
    myTimer.setForNowPlus(...);
  }

  @OnTimer(MY_TIMER)
  public void onMyTimer(
      OnTimerContext context,
      @StateId(MY_STATE) ValueState<Bizzle> bizzleState) {
    context.output(... bizzleState.read() ...);
    bizzleState.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I am actually wondering if I could achieve the same thing with a `Sessions` window maybe, instead of a global window.

Comment: Great blog post by the way!

Comment: Hi Kenn, could you please give an example of how Bizzle.coder() should be implemented, assuming Bizzle is a POJO containing some member fields which each already have coder implementation (e.g. Integer, Map, etc) ?

Comment: Also a quick question on state GC - if my window fires panes early and discards fired panes, would the state for the keys which were fired early be kept until after the window expires? i.e. would subsequent panes in the same window have access to state written by earlier panes?

Comment: I think I've answered my first question - we can just make Bizzle implement java.io.Serializable and then use SerializableCoder.of(Bizzle.class) as the coder

Comment: @josh that is a good question about speculative triggers that deserves its own answer. Can you ask it top level and link it here?

Comment: @peay in sessions, automatic GC will just work. But at this moment, our runners don't support state in merging windows. There's nothing stopping them - the API is the same for users but the backend implementation is much more complex.

Comment: @KennKnowles sorry for the late reply - I have created a new question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586372/stateful-processing-in-beam-is-state-shared-across-window-panes

Comment: @KennKnowles Is it possible that state is GCed after a window with no allowed lateness expires but before a timer like `expiryTimer.set(window.maxTimestamp().plus(allowedLateness))` gets executed?

Answer (score 1):

There is not automatic garbage collection of state if you use `GlobalWindows`. Only if you use some non-global window will state be garbage collected after the watermark passes the end of a window plus the allowed lateness.

What you can do if you must work with `GlobalWindows` is to manually keep as state the `last update timestamp`. Then you would periodically set a timer where you check this timestamp against the current time and delete state if necessary. You would set this timer when encountering a key for the first time (which you can see from the absence of your timestamp state) and then re-set it in the `@OnTimer` method.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. How does one delete a state? `stateCell.write(null)`? Won't this still leave an empty `ValueState` dangling?

Comment: Got it, found `clear` from Kenn's answer, not sure how I missed that.