# Stateful processing in Beam - is state shared across window panes?

Tags: state, apache-beam

Apache Beam has recently introduced state cells, through `StateSpec` and the `@StateId` annotation, with partial support in Apache Flink and Google Cloud Dataflow.

My question is about state garbage collection, in the case where a stateful DoFn is used on a windowed stream. Typically, state is removed (garbage collected) by the runner when the window expires (i.e. the watermark passes the end of the window). However, consider the case where window panes are triggered early, and the fired panes are discarded:

```java
input.apply(Window.<MyElement>into(CalendarWindows.days(1))
  .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
  .withEarlyFirings(
    AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
      .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(10))
  ))
  .discardingFiredPanes()
  .apply(ParDo.of(new MyStatefulDofn()));
```

In this case, would the state for the keys which were fired early be kept until after the window expires? i.e. would subsequent panes in the same window have access to state written by earlier panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triggering configuration does not affect how stateful processing of a `ParDo` proceeds. The elements are provided immediately to your `DoFn` without any buffering/triggering and your `DoFn` directly controls when output occurs.

The fact that you control the output is an important difference between stateful `ParDo` processing and `Combine.perKey` governed by triggers. This is why stateful `ParDo` is often a good choice when triggers are not rich enough for your use case.

I compare stateful `ParDo` processing with `Combine` + triggers in some more detail in my post on the Beam blog: https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html

Now, if there is a `GroupByKey` or `Combine.perKey` somewhere upstream from your stateful `ParDo`, then input elements will be associated with some trigger firing from upstream. But this does not affect how the state for your stateful `ParDo` is managed. As state is persisted across elements, and a "pane" is just an element, state is maintained until the window expires fully.

Very nice summary leading up to your question, by the way!