# How to calculate a running total with Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using the Apache Beam SDK for Google Dataflow I'd like to calculate a daily balance from a set of transactions.

An example data set may look like this with the name of the payee, the transaction date, and an amount:

```
John, 2017-12-01, 100
John, 2017-12-01, 200
Jane, 2017-12-01, 150
John, 2017-12-02, -100
John, 2017-12-02, 300
```

The desired result set would look like:

```
John, 2017-12-01, 300  (100 + 200)
Jane, 2017-12-01, 150
John, 2017-12-02, 500  (300 + -100 + 300)
```

I've tried using a `KV<Pair, BigDecimal>` with a `Combine.perKey` function that calculated the sum of the `BigDecimal` but that doesn't account for the previous day's ending balance as the starting balance for the next day.

Answer (score 4):

Beam's windowing API is the right thing to use here:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Specifically, you have to answer the questions:

1. **Where in event time would you like to perform aggregations?**
2. **When in processing time would you like your answer?**

There's not quite enough information in your post to answer these questions - you'd have to provide more specifics - are you running in batch or streaming mode? Do you want one answer at the end of each day, or do you want a running total that updates every time there's a new transaction? or something in between? If I had to guess, it sounds like you want to keep a global total (global event time window), and get an update once a day on the current value.

After we've answered the above questions, we can write some pseudo-code:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Double>> transactionsByName = .... ;     // Read input

PCollection<KV<String, Double> dailyTotalsByName = transactionsByName
  // Group by name
  .apply(GroupByKey.<String, Double>create())   
  // 1-day windows       
  .apply(Window.<KV<String, Iterable<Double>>>into(    
      FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardDays(1))))    
  // Combine each window (see combiners guide [here][1])  
  .apply(Combine.<String, Iterable<Double>, Double>perKey(new SumTotals())); 

PCollection<KV<String, Double> globalTotalsByName = dailyTotalsByName
  // Global windows allow you to combine a running total. Triggering condition
  // specifies 'when' in processing time the answers are materialized. Here we
  // have chosen to output the answer each time a new daily total arrives.
  .apply(Window.<KV<String, Iterable<Double>>>into(new GlobalWindows()))
     .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))))
  // Combine daily totals
  .apply(Combine.<String, Iterable<Double>, Double>perKey(new SumTotals()))
```

The above code might not build exactly as-is but outlines at least one reasonable approach. Of course depending on the specifics of your input and problem, you might need to adjust how often you are triggering, etc. As mentioned, this will only give you results at the end of each day. If you want a live running total, you can use more complex triggering conditions to output the current value.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The process I'm describing is a bounded batch process.  It's reading data from a Bigtable table at some ad-hoc schedule (could be anytime), calculating the daily balance, and writing results to another Bigtable table. In regards to windowing, I was under the impression that that was respective to the timestamp of the collection element not an arbitrary data element.  It may be that this process is processing today for data elements with dates in the past.

Comment: Perhaps you're suggesting I need to manually assign timestamps to the elements as described in https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements

Also, can you expand on the SumTotals() class, specifically what it extends or implements and its signature.  I cannot land on a solution which compiles.

Comment: Also important for keeping the state in a Global window is how to garbage collect it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773020/state-garbage-collection-in-beam-with-globalwindow/42774329

Comment: @MHartman did you ever manage to find a solution for this? I struggle with the same exact problem and the documentation for windowing is more than disappointing to the point where I can manage to get it to work.

Comment: @MHartman did you resolve this one? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler usecase of State in Beam. Once you have the key,value collection, you can apply GlobalWindow on that PCollection and then update the count by using State.

With Timers and State, we can actually output the data periodically if needed. In this case, it will output data only when new word or same word arrives, so if no data arrives for a given day, it will not output anything which may or may not be the behaviour you want.

If you're looking at more complicated output scenario, please review this post on [Timely and Stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/)

```java
PCollection<String> input; // read input
PCollection<String> output = input.apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptors.longs()))
    .via((String elem) -> KV.of(elem, 1L)))
  .apply(Window.<KV<String, Long>>into(new GlobalWindows())
  .apply(ParDo.of(new UpdateOccurrenceCountByWord()))
```

The `UpdateOccurrenceCountByWord` is the one where I am using State to store previous values. In this case, I only need to store the previous count.

```java
private static class UpdateOccurrenceCountByWord extends DoFn<KV<String, Long>, String> {
        private static final String WORD_COUNT = "word_count";

        @StateId(WORD_COUNT)
        private final StateSpec<BagState<Long>> wordsSeen = StateSpecs.bag();

        @ProcessElement
        public void process(@Element KV<String, Long> in, OutputReceiver<String> out, @StateId(WORD_COUNT) BagState<Long> counter) {
            List<Long> countsSoFar = Lists.newArrayList(counter.read());
            Long sum = in.getValue();
            for (Long value: countsSoFar) {
                sum += value;
            }
            countsSoFar.add(sum);
            counter.add(in.getValue());
            out.output(in.getKey().toString() + "," + sum.toString());
        }
}
```