# Find active users events every 60 seconds in Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-beam, windowing

I am trying to find active users for my game applications. In my use-case I have following scenario.
The input data source is Kafka topic with message like

```json
{"user_id": 123, "event_id": 1, "utc_ts": 1234345323}
{"user_id": 123, "event_id": 0, "utc_ts": 1234345323}
```

`event_id` 1 means login and 0 means logout.
My task is to run 60 second window operations and find all the active user records. So, for example,

```
|Input activity             | output      | Window   |
|user1 -> login -> 12:31:40 | user1 event | 12:31:59 |
|user2 -> login -> 12:31:42 | user2 event | 12:31:59 |
|user3 -> login -> 12:32:13 | user1, user2, user3 event | 12:32:59 |
|user2 -> logout -> 12:33:23| user1, user3 event | 12:33:59 |
```

Basically my output should be all the active user events in the last one day.
Previously, we were able to achieve this with `updateStateByKey` Spark function, which would look at the timestamp and if the event is new, it will output old + new events. If it's older event, it would output only old events.

I tried to implement this in Beam, but Beam seems to only produce data for current batch. The previous active records are basically not sent to output.

```java
PCollection<KV<Long, String>> userIdAndEvent = readPCollectionOfUserIdAndEvent()
PCollection<KV<Long, String>> output = userIdAndEvent.apply(ParDo.of(new BucketByUserId())
    .apply(Window.into(new GlobalWindows())

output.setCoder(KvCoder.of(VarLongCoder.of(), NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of())));

output.apply(ParDo.of(new UpdateStateByUserId()))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new WriteToKafka()))

private static class UpdateStateByUserId extends DoFn<KV<Long, String>, String> {
        private static final String EVENT_STATE = "event_state";
        private static final Long ONE_DAY = 86400L;

        @StateId(EVENT_STATE)
        private final StateSpec<ValueState<String>> eventState = StateSpecs.value(NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()));

        @ProcessElement
        public void process(@Element KV<Long, String> in, OutputReceiver<String> out, @StateId(EVENT_STATE) ValueState<String> eventState) {
            String currentEvent = Optional.ofNullable(eventState.read()).orElse("");
            Long userId = in.getKey();
            JSONObject newEvent = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(in.getValue());
            JSONObject stateEvent = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(currentEvent);
            Long stateEventTs = extractLong(stateEvent, "utc_ts").orElse(0L);
            Optional<Long> eventTs = extractLong(newEvent, "utc_ts");
            if (eventTs.isPresent()) {
                if (eventTs.get() < stateEventTs) {
                    eventState.write(eventState.read());
                } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L - eventTs.get() < ONE_DAY) {
                    eventState.write(newEvent.toJSONString());
                    out.output(newEvent.toJSONString());
                } else {
                    Optional<Long> eventId = extractLong(newEvent, "event_id");
                    if (eventId.isPresent() && eventId.get() == getLoginId()) {
                        eventState.write(newEvent.toJSONString());
                        out.output(newEvent.toJSONString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I'm not sure where to find answer to this. It's essentially similar to [this - finding running total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913563/how-to-calculate-a-running-total-with-apache-beam/47914551), but couldn't understand responses in that post. This is similar to finding running total but at the finish of window, output running total for all the words, not just the words that came in last window.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "data for current batch?" Also, I see your example input/output, but your code doesn't seem to do anything special with logout events, so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @robertwb Thanks for your comment. I was able to do this with the use of Timers and State.  I found the blog on Looping timers to be useful as it's similar to time series data. I still have some issue with outputting data exactly at 60 seconds rather than in the middle, but for the moment what I have should be fine.

Basically, I was looking to output all active users, every 60 seconds. If the user logs out, remove user State and there will not be any record for that user. If he logs back in, there will be event output for that user. After a day of inactivity, all users log out.

Comment: Yes this sample code doesn't have anything for logout event.

Comment: @robertwb I have another question. This is possible with Beam version > 2.31.0 because they have timer.clear() method. How do we clear timers for a key in earlier version in case you know.

Comment: IIUC, you need to apply a sliding window offset by 1-minute with length of 1-day since the state is per-key per-window to be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason events are being lost is that there are code paths in your `@ProcessElement` function which do not call `out.output()`. If that function is not called, the element will not be output. This code path seems like it would discard late arriving data, no?

```
if (eventTs.get() < stateEventTs) {
```

More generally, it seems like you are implementing Apache Beam windowing functions from scratch. Did you try using Apache Beam windowing functions like `FixedWindows`, `SlidingWindows`, etc? `FixedWindows` seems like it would fit your use case quite well.
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Note that you want to window on *event time*, not *processing time*. You will need to extract `utc_ts` from the Kafka message as it's being received. Looking at KafkaIO documentation, this appears to be configurable.
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html#withTimestampPolicyFactory-org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.TimestampPolicyFactory-

Comment: Alec, Thanks for your message. I have solved it with the help of State and Timers. It could also be done using SlidingWindow, but in that case, I didn't figure out exact logic for `CombineFn` implementation.

Comment: `CombineFn` works the same way in the context of Sliding Windows as it does in the context of a batch pipeline (defaulting to Global Window). Combination is done per-window. This is one of the innovations of Beam: streaming and batch pipelines use the same underlying model.